# Most concise, robust way to temporarily stash stream formats?

Tags: c++

I got tired of the boilerplate and tedium restoring formatting context, so I made an RAII stasher that relies on the destroy-at-end-of-full-statement temporary semantics. With C++17 I can get it down to a single type, no helpers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template< template<typename, class> class streamtmp, typename _CharT, class _Traits >
struct fmtstash {
    typedef streamtmp<_CharT,_Traits> streamtype;
    streamtype &from;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags flags;
    std::streamsize width;
    std::streamsize precision;
    fmtstash(streamtype &str) :
        from(str), flags(str.flags()), width(str.width()), precision(str.precision()) { }
    ~fmtstash() { from.flags(flags), from.width(width), from.precision(precision); }
    template<typename _T> streamtype  &operator<<(const _T &rhs) { return from.operator<<(rhs); }
    template<typename _T> streamtype  &operator>>(const _T &rhs) { return from.operator>>(rhs); }
};

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    using namespace std;
    fmtstash(cout) << hex << 51901 <<'\n';
    cout << 51901 <<'\n';


    return 0;
}
```

which produces about the easiest-to-write-and-read formatting I can manage.

Am I missing any bets here? Shorter or more robust is what I'm after.

Comment: If this code is functional but you want critique, [codereview.se] is the place.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica right. It works, this is a "use, improve, scrap" question. I'll ask there.

Comment: That's about as good as you can do.

Comment: Don't use identifiers starting with underscore followed by capital letter. These identifiers are reserved to the compiler/standard library in all contexts.

Comment: Just scrap iostreams. `std::format` is coming.